# how to fix the error no. -4078, in mongoose connection to the server what's cause this?

Tags: mongodb

**What is wrong with this setup**

'''
nodejs
'''

```
require('dotenv').config()
// console.log(process.env)

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const expressLayouts = require("express-ejs-layouts")
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


app.set("view engine", "ejs")
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views")
app.set('layout', "layouts/layout")
app.use(expressLayouts)
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use('/', indexRouter)


mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/printshop',{
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}
)

const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', error=>  console.log(error))
db.once('open', ()=>  console.log('connected to mongogoose'))


app.listen(process.env.PORT)
```

im trying to connect to mongodb in my local network but suddenly this
**error message**
just out

```
 MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Connection.openUri (E:\nodejs\node-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:825:32)
    at E:\nodejs\node-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:417:10       
    at E:\nodejs\node-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (E:\nodejs\node-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (E:\nodejs\node-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1270:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (E:\nodejs\node-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:416:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\nodejs\node-server\server.js:20:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1166:10) {   
  reason: TopologyDescription {
   queues:82:21) {
      cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
          at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1237:16) {
        errno: -4078,
        code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '::1',
        port: 27017
      },
      [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
    },
    topologyVersion: null,
    setName: null,
    setVersion: null,
    electionId: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    primary: null,
    me: null,
    '$clusterTime': null
  }
},
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: null,
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
```

},
code: undefined

what the mean?

*im looking for the log of "***connected to mongogoose"*** but it doesnt show in console then the error comes
ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
what is this mean?*

Answer (score 2):

if anyone had a problem like this you can fix it by changing the

```
mongoodb://localhost/
```

**to**

```
mongoodb://127.0.0.1/
```